# Delete remote repo from git using terminal

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How can I delete remote repo using terminal?

I have tried `rm -rf .git`.

This delete file from local but does not delete repository from remote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot delete remote repository, you must use the tools provided by your hosting platform (Gitlab, Github, BitBucket, ...).

Comment: Note that these tools differ per hosting system, so there's no single answer to "how do I delete the repo on <insert hosting system here>": that's one question per hosting system!

Comment: Exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete files recursively on Git, you have to use the “git rm” command with the “-r” option for recursive and specify the list of files to be deleted.

```
$ git rm -r <folder>

$ git commit -m "Deleted the folder from the repository"

$ git push
```